# SAS Get rid of "duplicate" variables

Tags: sas, duplicates

I'm new to SAS and I have a question I hope you can help me with.

I am looking at some grades for different students in different subjects - here is an example.

[image]

But I want it to look like this so each person is only mentioned once.

[image]

Can anyone please help me how to do that?

Comment: Don't post photographs of your data.  Include the data in the questions so others can use it help answer your question.

Comment: You could have at least bothered to `enter image description here`, as suggested...

Comment: Sorry thought it would put the images into the message directly because I didn't know how to write it in columns. But I'll remember that for another time. But thank you for your helpfull reply though :)

Comment: just copy the text here and indent it by 4 spaces or press the code button, it'll width be remain as formatted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the UPDATE statement to collapse multiple records to have the latest non-missing value.

```
data have ;
  input id (course1-course3) ($) ;
cards;
1 B . . 
1 . A .
1 . . A
2 C . .
2 . C .
2 . . D 
;

data want ;
  update have(obs=0) have;
  by id;
run;
```